# Setting .plist path to user Library

Tags: macos, plist, daemons, launchd

I have created a OS X launch agent that is installed per user. It is listening socket and automatically launched when socket connection arrives. On my .plist I have

```
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
<string>~/Library/Containers/com.mycompany.myproduct/myproduct.app/Contents/MacOS/myproduct</string>
    </array>
```

When connecting to my launch agent socket I get a message in console saying my launch agent is not found. When changing .plist ProgramArguments to

```
<string>/Users/myusername/Library/Containers/com.mycompany.myproduct/myproduct.app/Contents/MacOS/myproduct</string>
```

Launch agent is loaded correctly. So it looks like I need to modify .plist for each user during launch agent installation. How can I do this automatically or easily? Is there a standard way for this? Or should I do something totally differently here to achieve what I want?

Comment: Why not install for all users and so in /Library/Containers/com.mycompany.myproduct/....

Comment: Mark, my user agent is a helper app for Mac App Store app - should I then install it for all users? Users can download the helper from my website to extend main app functionality beyond sandbox limits. If yes I should probably also move launch agent from ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ to /Library/LaunchAgents/ ?

Comment: Also, there is no directory /Library/Containers/ on my Mac, should I just create one for my launch agent to work?

Answer (score 1):

Use EnableGlobbing:

```
<key>EnableGlobbing</key>
<true/>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>~/Library/Containers/com.mycompany.myproduct/myproduct.app/Contents/MacOS/myproduct</string>
</array>
```

It works with ProgramArguments but not with Program.

Comment: I thought there is something like this, but never seen it before. Brilliant.

Comment: Based on documents this is what I need, but after adding EnableGlobbing to my plist I still get the same error.

Comment: I solved the problem by installing launch agent to /Library/LaunchAgents.